# Python Pandas Stock Data Gap Fill

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm testing a strategy to trade on gap fill.

Given that AAPL created an upward gap on 2022-10-04 and filled this gap on 2022-10-07 (and there will be multiple gaps), how to identify if the nearest upward gap is filled in a pythonic way?

Code:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr

df = pdr.data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start='2022-07-28', end='2022-09-01')
df['upward_gap'] = df['Low'] > df['High'].shift(1)  # identify upward gap
df['upward_gap_no'] = df['upward_gap'].cumsum()
```

Current Output:

```
                  High         Low  ...  upward_gap  upward_gap_no
Date                                ...                           
2022-08-08  167.809998  164.199997  ...       False              0
2022-08-09  165.820007  163.250000  ...       False              0
2022-08-10  169.339996  166.899994  ...        True              1
2022-08-11  170.990005  168.190002  ...       False              1
2022-08-12  172.169998  169.399994  ...       False              1
2022-08-15  173.389999  171.350006  ...       False              1
2022-08-16  173.710007  171.660004  ...       False              1
2022-08-17  176.149994  172.570007  ...       False              1
2022-08-18  174.899994  173.119995  ...       False              1
2022-08-19  173.740005  171.309998  ...       False              1
2022-08-22  169.860001  167.139999  ...       False              1
2022-08-23  168.710007  166.649994  ...       False              1
2022-08-24  168.110001  166.250000  ...       False              1
2022-08-25  170.139999  168.350006  ...        True              2
2022-08-26  171.050003  163.559998  ...       False              2
2022-08-29  162.899994  159.820007  ...       False              2
2022-08-30  162.559998  157.720001  ...       False              2
2022-08-31  160.580002  157.139999  ...       False              2
```

Expected Output (open to any better representation):

```
                  High         Low  ...  upward_gap  upward_gap_no
Date                                ...                           
2022-08-08  167.809998  164.199997  ...       False              0
2022-08-09  165.820007  163.250000  ...       False              0
2022-08-10  169.339996  166.899994  ...        True              1  - 1st upward gap
2022-08-11  170.990005  168.190002  ...       False              1
2022-08-12  172.169998  169.399994  ...       False              1
2022-08-15  173.389999  171.350006  ...       False              1
2022-08-16  173.710007  171.660004  ...       False              1
2022-08-17  176.149994  172.570007  ...       False              1
2022-08-18  174.899994  173.119995  ...       False              1
2022-08-19  173.740005  171.309998  ...       False              1
2022-08-22  169.860001  167.139999  ...       False              1
2022-08-23  168.710007  166.649994  ...       False              1
2022-08-24  168.110001  166.250000  ...       False              1
2022-08-25  170.139999  168.350006  ...        True              2  - 2nd upward gap
2022-08-26  171.050003  163.559998  ...       False              0  - Both 1st & 2nd gap filled
2022-08-29  162.899994  159.820007  ...       False              0
2022-08-30  162.559998  157.720001  ...       False              0
2022-08-31  160.580002  157.139999  ...       False              0
```

Comment: What is the criteria or formula to determine that the gap is filled?

Comment: Is that when the high value drops below the original 1st day high value ?

Comment: @ScottC Thanks for the question. The gap is filled once the low drop below the high of previous 1 day before the gap, i.e. AAPL's low on 2022-10-07 is below the high on 2022-10-03

Comment: isn't the low on 2022-10-05 ..[`143.009995`]  below the high on the 2022-10-03.. [`143.070007`] ?  Why is the gap not filled on the 5th ?

Comment: @ScottC Yup you're right, thanks so much. Let me change to another sample.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - while this is not exactly what you were hoping for, I think I have something that somewhat satisfies the requirements. I have not done anything with additional hierarchies of gaps, however, have accommodated for the base gap (or what you are calling `upward gap 1`).

- The `check_gap` value (**orange**) is used to identify the row containing the `high_check` number.
- The `high_check` number (**yellow**) is the `High` value that is being used to identify when the gap is filled.
- The `upward_gap` number (**green**) remains `True` until the `Low` value drops below the `high_check` number.
- The `high_check` numbers (**blue**) are being identified, but are being ignored because they are within another upward_gap.

```py
import pandas_datareader as pdr

df = pdr.data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start='2022-07-28', end='2022-09-01')
df['check_gap'] = (df['Low'] > df['High'].shift(1)).shift(-1).fillna(False)  # identify upward gap

start_checking = False
previous = False
skip_one = False
high_check = 0
upward_gap = []
high_check_list = []

for (cg, low, high) in zip(df['check_gap'], df['Low'], df['High']):
    if cg and not start_checking:
        start_checking = True
        high_check = high
        skip_one = True
    
    if start_checking and not skip_one:
        if low < high_check:
            start_checking = False
            high_check = 0
    elif skip_one:
        skip_one = False
        
    if start_checking and cg and not previous:
        high_check_list.append(0)
        upward_gap.append(False)
    else:
        upward_gap.append(start_checking)
        high_check_list.append(high_check)
        
    previous = start_checking
    
    
df['high_check'] = high_check_list
df['upward_gap'] = upward_gap

df
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: Output]

...

[image: Output]